# Can't find /etc/default/grub

Tags: distributions, ubiquity

`/etc/default/grub` does just not seem to exist on my system. I have a Raspberry Pi 3b+ running ubuiqityrobot which is an Ubuntu version with OS pre-installed.

I want to find this GRUB file to edit one line of code to stop the loading dots from boot to remain in the center of my screen.

My question is. Where is my `/etc/default/grub` file?

Comment: So what happens when you input: cat /etc/default/grub

Answer (score 8):

Your observation is correct. Raspberry Pi does not use GRUB at all.

GRUB is not universal in the Linux world, but a bootloader for some specific hardware architectures:

- 32- and 64-bit x86 PCs, using BIOS, UEFI or Coreboot firmware
- PowerPCs
- SPARC systems
- MIPS Lemote Yeeloong systems
- certain Qemu emulation environments.

Raspberry Pi is an ARM device, which is none of the above. It has its own firmware and bootloader.

The first stage bootloader is stored in ROM within the RasPi's system-on-chip.
It loads `bootcode.bin` from the SD card. That will load `start.elf`, which will then load `config.txt`, `cmdline.txt` and `kernel.img`. In older versions of RasPi firmware, there used to be `loader.bin` step in between `bootcode.bin` and `start.elf`.

More details:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/10489

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=6685

`config.txt` settings: http://rpf.io/configtxtreadme

`cmdline.txt` is the place for the Linux kernel boot options.

Comment: So where can we set the boot resolution on RPI *(I know each ARM system has different settings)*? Modern Linux on i386 architecture uses KMS and we set `GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x800` and `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep` in `/etc/defaults/grub` and then rebuilt the Grub with `sudo update-grub` and `sudo reboot`.

Comment: @71GA In `/boot/config.txt`, there should be commented-out lines with `hdmi_group`, `hdmi_mode`, `framebuffer_width` and `framebuffer_height`, ready to be uncommented and adjusted as needed. See http://rpf.io/configtxtreadme for more info. Once the Linux kernel is up and running, there is also the `fbset` command which can be used to change the display mode as needed.